# unordered_map of different custom types

Tags: c++, stl

Suppose if I have these two `enums`:

```
enum Type
{
    Type1,
    Type2
};

enum Location
{
    Location1,
    Location2,
    Location3
};
```

Now I would like to have a container that I can reference like `container[Type1][Location1] = 5;`

I don't need the elements to be sorted but I need to be able to have duplicates like `container[Type1]` can be either `Location1` or `Location2` etc.

I was thinking to use an `unordered_multimap<pair<Type, Location>, unsigned int>>` which kind of provides what I want, but does not allow me to access the elements as described (or at least I don't know how to do that)

What suggestions do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for nested maps:

```
std::unordered_map<Type, std::unordered_map<Location, unsigned int>>
```

Comment: Can you also show an example of how to insert/access elements in such a nested map? (sorry about this it's just my first time with maps other than `map<string, string>`)

Comment: @TedyS.: Simple access is `container[Type1][Location1]`, as you wanted. Then there's the [rest of the interface](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) if you need to do anything more complicated.

Comment: Thanks, got it all sorted out.